# Different result of css grid in Chrome and MS Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I'm pretty new at web dev so Im not really sure whats wrong here. Im using bootstrap grid. Here is the css:

```
body {
    background: #252525;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    overflow: auto;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.grid-container > * {
    position: absolute
}


.login-box {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
            <div class="login-box container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <form id="frmLogin">
                        <div class="col-md-12 clear-margin-padding text-center">
                            <h4>Login to service</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 clear-margin-padding" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <table>
                                <col width="90">
                                <col width="*">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email</td>
                                    <td><input type="email" id="txtEmail" required></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password</td>
                                    <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" required></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 clear-margin-padding text-center" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <div class="wrap-panel">
                                <button type="button" id="btnRegister">Register</button>
                                <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="col-md-12 clear-margin-padding text-center" style="margin-top: 5px">
                        <a href="/recovery">Forgot my password</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Result in Edge]

[image: Result in Chrome]

Im not sure who is wrong here but for sure it is caused by the

```
position: absolute;
```

What I want to accomplish is make the login box centered and when I want to add more 'box' to the grid-container, I can position them based on align-self and justify-self so the grid-container can act like WPF's Grid control.

Any help is appreciated.

**Another example (same .grid-container):**

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
            <div style="width:100px;height:100px;align-self:start;justify-self: left;background: black"></div>
            <div style="width:100px;height:100px;align-self:center;justify-self: center;background: black"></div>
            <div style="width:100px;height:100px;align-self:end;justify-self: right;background: black"></div>
        </div>
```

[MS Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ8QM.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEUDr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be ms edge's fault I think because of `position: absolute` on my css code. I have managed to not use absolute positioning and everything is working good. Thanks for the help anyways! :)

Answer (score -1):

To fix your problem just remove the `display: grid` from the grid container and `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`. Now the `.grid-container` should be as follows:

```
 .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

and remove `align-self: center; justify-self: center;` from your `.login-box`, that `.login-box` should be as follows:

```
.login-box {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

you can find an updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/175997/).

In general since you are not using CSS Grid, I would advise to drop `display: grid` as when targeting IE, using `display: grid` is not the most advised approach since the **support is limited to IE 10+ and even then the support is partial** and for an older specification of the grid for example `justify-self justify-content align-self align-content` are not supported or jaggy.

Feel free to ask any questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Edge is not IE. Edge has full support for the latest grid specification: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: It was a general side note, check the fiddle for an answer to your problem and if it's not working let me know.